# Ignored property not returned in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-fluent-api

I have a blog model and a blog comment model. The blog has a collection of blog comments associated with it however when I'm getting all my blogs so that I can list them out on some sort of summary page, I don't want to be pulling all the comments as well, I only need the comments when I select a specific blog and go to it's page. However, I do want the count of the comments to be displayed on the summary section.

I've created a stored procedure for retrieving the blogs which doesn't return any comments but does return a value for the count of the comments associated with the blog.

When selecting a specific blog, I will simply let EF grab it for me rather than using a stored procedure.

The problem I'm having is that I don't want the comment count to be a column in the blog table so initially I thought I should ignore it in the OnModelCreating method using fluent api. However, this means that when I run my stored procedure, it does not return the value which my stored procedure should be giving me.

Blog Class:

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid BlogGuid { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public IList<BlogComment> Comments { get; set; }
    public int CommentCount { get; set; }

    public Blog()
    {
        Comments = new List<BlogComment>();
    }
}
```

Blog Comment Class:

```
public class BlogComment
{
    public Guid BlogCommentGuid { get; set; }
    public Guid BlogGuid { get; set; }
    public int ContactRef { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var blog = modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
    blog.ToTable("Blogs");
    blog.HasKey(b => b.BlogGuid);
    blog.HasMany(b => b.Comments).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.BlogGuid);
    blog.Ignore(b => b.CommentCount);

    var blogComment = modelBuilder.Entity<BlogComment>();
    blogComment.ToTable("BlogComments");
    blogComment.HasKey(c => c.BlogCommentGuid);
}
```

Get Blogs Method:

```
public IList<Blog> GetBlogs()
{
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<Blog>("Get_Blogs").ToList();
}
```

Stored procedure code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Blogs 
(
    BlogGuid uniqueidentifier, 
    Title nvarchar(50), 
    Text nvarchar(MAX), 
    Author nvarchar(50), 
    DatePosted datetime
)

IF (@BlogCount IS NOT NULL AND @BlogCount > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Blogs
        SELECT TOP (@BlogCount) *
            FROM Blogs
            ORDER BY DatePosted DESC
END ELSE BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Blogs
        SELECT *
            FROM Blogs
            ORDER BY DatePosted DESC
END

SELECT *,

    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM BlogComments
        WHERE BlogComments.BlogGuid = #Blogs.BlogGuid) CommentCount

FROM #Blogs

DROP TABLE #Blogs
```

When calling `GetBlogs()`, `CommentCount` is always zero even when blogs do have comments in the blog comment table.

I think I understand why this is happening, I just can't think of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a solution for this which is to create a superclass for the blog called `BlogSummary` which has the `CommentCount` property on it. I've then set this to be ignored in the `OnModelCreating` method.

BlogSummary:

```
public class BlogSummary: Blog
{
    public int CommentCount { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Blog
    var blog = modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
    blog.ToTable("Blogs");
    blog.HasKey(b => b.BlogGuid);
    blog.HasMany(b => b.Comments).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.BlogGuid);

    // Blog Summary
    modelBuilder.Ignore<BlogSummary>();

    // Blog Comment
    var blogComment = modelBuilder.Entity<BlogComment>();
    blogComment.ToTable("BlogComments");
    blogComment.HasKey(c => c.BlogCommentGuid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I'd just put a `Count` call in the `get` of `CommentCount.

```
public int CommentCount { get { return this.Comments.Count; } set; }
```

Comment: Surely this means I'm retrieving all the comments so that I can count them though? That's what I'm trying to avoid - needlessly loading all the comments where I don't need them.

Comment: @AndyFurniss worry about getting things working first. If you find you have performance issues after, then you can work on optimizations like this.

Comment: Yeah I had it all working without this comment count stuff and then started trying to implement it once I realised it was pointless returning all the comments from the database. Counting the comments in the database is surely less expensive than shipping them over the internet?